# Can I use @for loop in emotion-js, similarly to @for in sass?

Tags: sass, emotion

In sass if I write:

`@for $i from 1 through 3
  li:nth-child(#{$i})
    transition-delay: #{$i * 0.3}s`

, I can get a nice progressive transition delay for each list element.

Is it possible to do this with emotion-js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I have figured it.

First I create a JS function, which does my loop and then returns the styles as an object

```
const menuListTrans = () => {
  let styles = {};
  for (let $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    styles["&:nth-child(" + $i + ")"] = {
      transitionDelay: "1s," + $i * 0.08 + "s",
    };
  }
  return styles;
};
```

and then interpolate it in the styled component

```
const MenuList = styled.ul`
  &.expanded > li {
    transform: translateY(0);
    ${menuListTrans}
  }
`;
```

Comment: I could hug you, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

here is the same approach but with variables.

```
export const nthChildDelay = ({ count = 10, delay = 100, multiplier = 80 }) => {
  const styles = {};
  [...Array(count).keys()].forEach((_, index) => {
    if (index !== 0) {
      styles[`&:nth-child(${index})`] = {
        transitionDelay: `${delay + (index - 1) * multiplier}ms`,
      };
    }
  });
  return styles;
};
```

And then use it as

```
${nthChildDelay({ count: 10, delay: 100, multiplier: 100 })};
```